# How to add buttons to an embed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

So me and my friend have an embed,

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!help"):
        HelpEmbed = discord.Embed(
            title="Help screen",
            description=
            "Here is you can find instructions of how to use the bot!",
            color=discord.Colour.blue())
        HelpEmbed.add_field(
            name="Game Commands",
            value=
            "These are commands to do stuff in the game, use !GameCMDS to see all commands relate to the game",
            inline=False)
        HelpEmbed.add_field(
            name="Server commands",
            value=
            "These are commands to do stuff with the server. Use !ServerCMDS to see all commands related to the server",
            inline=False)
        HelpEmbed.set_thumbnail(
            url=
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477959858617-67f85cf4f1df?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1244&q=80"
        )
        await message.channel.send(embed=HelpEmbed)
```

We want to add buttons to it, however all tutorials do not work. My friend also could not figure out how, so if you know please tell me, also if you could tell me how to add a footer because `HelpEmbed.set_footer` does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discord.py v2:**

Since discord.py 2.0 release, interactions are now availible
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3.2/api.html#discord.Message.components

**Old answer:**

Take a look at discord-ineraction, a python library for discord components (buttons, selects, slash commands, ...)
[GitHub](https://github.com/goverfl0w/discord-interactions), [Docs](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Firts, install the library

```
$ pip install -U discord-py-interactions
```

According to the docs, you can use [create_button](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/stable/components.html):

```
from discord_slash.utils.manage_components import create_button, create_actionrow
from discord_slash.model import ButtonStyle

# ...

buttons = [
            create_button(
                style=ButtonStyle.green,
                label="A Green Button"
            ),
          ]

action_row = create_actionrow(*buttons)

await message.channel.send(embed=HelpEmbed, components=[action_row])
```

As for the footer, you can set [embed.set_footer()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_footer):

```
embed.set_footer(text="My Footer")
```

Comment: I noticed you deleted your original answer and posted this one that's nearly identical. Please use the [edit] button to edit your answer instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot! But how do I control what the button does, for example I want the button to send another embed?

Comment: Check the Wait_for part in the [docs](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/stable/components.html)

Comment: Hello, I looked at the documents, and I do not understand at all how to use it, and my bot doesnt work with ctx stuff which I have no idea what it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "my bot doesnt work with ctx", [__``Context``__](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) is a required argument for every command function.

Comment: Yeah but Im using stuff like on message event

Comment: You should consider using the [__`@bot.command()`__](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py) events for commands though