# Pycord leaderboard pagination

Tags: python, python-3.x, pagination, leaderboard, pycord

I have a leaderboard stored in a multi line string

1. Ben: 100
2. Tom : 70
3. Bill: 50
4. Linda: 30
5. John: 10
   How can I display 2 people in each page with for loop?

[This is what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTJsr.png)

This is my current code https://replit.com/@NotchApple1703/Notchapple1703#main.py

I don't know what to do next

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take look into [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also share the minimal efforts on your work.

Comment: The picture you're showing is an [Embed](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#embed). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786630/how-to-add-buttons-to-an-embed-in-discord-py)